# class fadeIn issue

Tags: jquery, css

The following script makes the class 'closeBox' fadin in several times before it stops (like some sort of animation). I only need it to fade it in once.

```
.box-holder div{
    background-color:#CCC;
    width:240px;
    height:240px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.closeBox{
    display:none;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}

.box-1{
    right:600px;
}

.box-2{
    right:310px;
}

.box-3{
    right:20px;
}
        <div class="box-holder" >
           <div class="box-1"
           data--50-top="right:600px;"
           data--300-top="right: -570px;"
           data-anchor-target="#slide-1 h2"
           ></div>
           <div class="box-2"
           data--50-top="right:310px;"
           data--300-top="right: -570px;"
           data-anchor-target="#slide-1 h2"
           ></div>
           <div class="box-3"
           data--50-top="right:20px;"
           data--300-top="right: -570px;"
           data-anchor-target="#slide-1 h2"
           ><p class="closeBox">X</p></div>
        </div> 

        $(document).ready(function(e) {

            var scrolling = $window.scrollTop();

            function update(){
                var boxHolderDivRight = $('.box-holder div').css('right'),
                    boxHolder = $('#slide-1 .box-holder'),
                    boxHolderDiv = $('.box-1, .box-2, .box-3'),
                    closeBox= $('.closeBox');

                    boxHolderDiv.click(function(){
                        if(boxHolderDiv.css('right') == -570+'px'){
                            boxHolderDiv.addClass('clicked');
                            closeBox.fadeIn();
                        }
                        else if(boxHolderDiv.css('right') == -300+'px' && boxHolderDiv.hasClass('clicked')){
                            boxHolderDiv.removeClass('clicked');
                            closeBox.fadeOut();
                        }
                    });


            }

            $window.bind('scroll', update);// JavaScript Document

        });
```

Comment: why are you registering the click handler inside a scroll event handelr

Comment: ah good point, would that be the reason? Thank you

Comment: yes every time the scroll event is called a new click handler gets registered

Comment: I'm not seeing any need for an scroll handler there... try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LZ9z5/1/

Comment: Hi yes guys, it's now fixed however I need to attach a click event on the closeBox class as it will allow me to close the box. Is it a good practice to attach a click event inside another one or is there a better way?

Comment: registering an event inside another one can always cause problems because of multiple registration issues.... otherwise you need to properly remove the previously registered handlers... why do you need to register an event inside another one

Comment: I originally click on the box to slide it, once the box is open then a cross ('.closeBox') fades in so that I can click it and close it.

Comment: Just register the handler on the close box once. When it's faded out, the user won't be able to click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually wrong to bind one event handler inside another event handler, since you'll get multiple event bindings unless you take care to remove the old one first. You should bind the second handler just once at top-level. If it needs to be dependent on something in first handler, have the first handler set a variable that the second one checks. If your first handler creates elements dynamically, or moves classes around, you can use delegation with `.on()` to have the handler automatically follow these changes. If you just want to enable and disable clicking on an input element, you can add and remove its `disabled` property. But you don't need to do this if you hide the element -- the user can't click on what they can't see.

Answer (score 1):

you are binding objects multiple times, it seems. you should do .unbind on the click events before re-binding.